# The site entrance

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, architecture

[image]

The entrance to a site from the road is being recessed and has a drop off zone in front of it. There is an architectural term for this type of entry. Can anyone help me out with that?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. We can give you answers the general public might accept, like *driveway*, but if you need a technical term, you are likely to be better-off asking subject matter experts, rather than language experts. What research have you attempted thus far?

Comment: yeah I need the technical term and it, being the actual term I thought maybe someone here could suggest me some. I believe some of your language experts might know that. in general they just say drop off zone or hoarded area but I need to know the name of the entrance with this drop off area in the front.

Comment: From the nature of either the Question or the graphic, I guess you're at least something close to a qualified architect; is that right?

Then what did your colleagues or teachers say, please? Look at the wording of your own Question to see this isn't about general English…

Answer (score 1):

If it's covered with a roof, I believe the architectural term is "porte-cochère" (from French).

With no roof though, I'm not sure. Colloquially, it would just be called something like "driveway," "drop off area," or "valet parking zone."

Answer (score 0):

A drop-off zone at an elementary school may be called

[image: kiss n go]

Comment: I'm not sure that "Kiss & Go" is the technical term OP is looking for.